# "net/url" can't parse url with pound

Tags: go

I have next code.

**main.go:**

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/url"

func main() {
    connString := "postgresql://postgres:password@192.168.1.10:5432/postgres"
    parsedUrl, err := url.Parse(connString)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("=")
    fmt.Println(parsedUrl.User)
    fmt.Println("=")
}
```

**Execution:**

```
$ go run main.go
=
postgres:password
=
```

**So far so good,** you could see we successfully get `parsedUrl.User` as `postgres:password`. Problems happens when I change the password to `password#` which has a bound in it.

```
connString := "postgresql://postgres:password#@192.168.1.10:5432/postgres"
```

Then, run it again, it outputs as next:

```
=

=
```

You could see the code can't fetch `postgres:password#`. It looks `#` in html would be treat as anchor, is this the root cause?

**To sum all, my question is:** how I could fix my code to handle the situation which I have `#` in password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `#` [indicates a fragment](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/url/url.go#L477-L485).

A way to solve it would be to escape the `#` character:

```golang
connString := fmt.Sprintf("postgresql://postgres:password%s@192.168.1.10:5432/postgres", url.PathEscape("#"))

parsedUrl, _ := url.Parse(connString)

fmt.Println(url.PathUnescape(parsedUrl.User.String()))
```

And the output:

```
postgres:password# <nil>
```

Comment: The other answer suggests using `QueryEscape()`. Which one is correct?

Comment: Looks `PathEscape` is identical to `QueryEscape` except that `PathEscape` will encode space to `%20`, while `QueryEscape` will encode space to `+`. `QueryEscape` will have issue when call `parsedUrl.User.Password()` later if my password also have space there like `pass+ word#`. So I choose `PathEscape` as my perfer this time as it looks meet more situation of different passwords although a litte strange that `PathUnescape` can't found in my local(golang 1.12), but it's not a big issue.

Comment: [url.PathUnescape](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#PathUnescape) was introduced in `go 1.8` - it should be available in `go 1.12`

Comment: Although the `url.PathUnescape` is not my question, but @colm.anseo Thanks for reminder, YES, my fault to assign return value of `url.Parse(connString)` to `url` again, the `url.PathUnescape` works indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `url.QueryEscape()`

Example

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    connString := `postgresql://postgres:` + url.QueryEscape(`password#`) + `@192.168.1.10:5432/postgres`
    xurl, err := url.Parse(connString)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("=")

    fmt.Println(xurl.User.Username())
    fmt.Println(xurl.User.Password())
    fmt.Println("=")
}
```

Comment: I like the `xurl.User.Password()` here as it works without calling any unescape, that's magic & brings thoughts to me, so I upvote this also, thanks, can't understand why guys will downvote it without any explain.

Comment: I second the kudos on the `url.User..Password()`. Maybe the downvotes we're due to the escape differences of `QueryEscape` vs `PathEscape`. Can anyone verify that a password with `space : # & /` works or not with postgres using either escaped connection string?

Comment: @colm.anseo, i did this example: https://play.golang.org/p/pNuBsWf-U_i

with `PathEscape`  `space : # & /` works. but not the same result using.  `QueryEscape `.... i m confused.

// output of example:
` password := `#:/password # / :` `


= PathEscape =
postgres
#:/password # / : true
=
=====================
= QueryEscape =
postgres
#:/password+#+/+: true
=

Comment: That settles it. `PathEscape` works with this method of `url.User.Password()` extraction - but not `QueryEscape`. You can see the difference in the encoding of the [two methods here](https://play.golang.org/p/e_n5QIl0xkm). I'd also like to verify a postgres *server* with a password set accepts this type of connection string.

Comment: FYI I just confirmed a `postgresql 13` server, set with a password with a litany of special characters, accepts `url. PathEscape` escaping - and fails with `url.QueryEscape` - as expected.